# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext wasteful?

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontextref

Is it not wasteful that there is a requirement that if you want to draw into a UIImage, that it always has to be into a new UIImage created with UIGraphicsBeginImageContext?

If frequent drawing needs to happen, why not let us draw into a preexisting UIImage?

Or is there a way to do this already?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `UIImage` is not mutable. If you are constantly rendering to a new `CGBitmapContext`, then you are doing something wrong in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Nope there is not, but you could have a context that you keep updating it before you realize it to an image, that is one way to not begin a context and end it, keep it open for further drawings

Comment: Use the following 

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, imageSize.width, imageSize.height, 8, imageSize.width * 4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst)

Comment: Yes you could draw a context in the UIView -drawrect function

Comment: use CGImageRef only if you want to realize it to an uiimage (png, jpg, etc...) check the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550201/how-exactly-to-make-a-cgimageref-from-an-image-on-disk